# How to use the iOS Photos app built in edit feature in code

Tags: ios, iphone, photosframework

You will notice in the iOS Photos app, when you tap a image, the right bar button item is edit, when you tap the edit, the image editor appears. I am wondering is there any API that I can implement so I can present this editor view controller in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you should present an UIImagePickerViewController an then set allowsEditing value true to present a editor after select the photo

Then with the UIImagePickerDelegate protocol you will be able to get the edited picture

[UIImagePicker documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/allowsEditing)

Comment: it is showing me only crop option not showing other like native camera